# AdvancedFilter to identify unique values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find unique values from column A in test sheet, and post them to column A in result sheet.

The data is a list/column of name (string), A1 ("Name") is the header in both sheets.

This is part of the VBA code:

```vb
With Sheets("test")
  .Range("A2:A243").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheet("result").Range("A2"), Unique:=True
End With
```

Problem is that for example if cell A2 and A100 in the test sheet have the same value, then after running the macro, column A in the result sheet would have that value twice.

Comment: Could you describe your data i.e. if there are headers, are they in `A1` or `A2`? You usually do this by including the header in the range. Also, the ¨result sheet¨' header has to be the same or missing.

Comment: The data is a list/column of name (string), A1 ("Name") is the header in both sheets.

Comment: Then you have to use `A1` as the starting cells: `.Range("A1:A243").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheet("result").Range("A1"), Unique:=True`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you test this values that are duplicated in excel. In the empty cell, type =A2=A100. If the result is True the problem is in the advanced filter, if - False, values are different.